# How to preserve the image size when copying it to the clipboard with PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to do the following: copy the compressed image to the clipboard via PowerShell.

The overall process looks like this: take a screenshot (outside of the PS script) -> compress it with pngquant (outside of the PS script) -> copy it to the clipboard (current issue)

```bsh
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms');
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Drawing');
$n,$e='%input'.split('.');
$fn=-join($n, '_compressed.', $e);
$f=get-item($fn);
$img=[System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile($f);
[System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::SetImage($img);
$img.Dispose()
```

The `%input` gets replaced by the full file path + extension. For example, `Z:\image.png`.
Pardon the formatting, it's supposed to be the one liner, so trying to keep it short.

For example, if the compressed image is 760KB down from the original 3MB, after I copy it to the clipboard it becomes 2MB. Quite frankly, the same thing happens when I press "copy" in the default windows image viewer.

However, since we are working with PS here, maybe there's some kind of workaround?

Comment: If you want to place the compressed image file into the clipboard, use `[System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::SetFileDropList()`. Otherwise there's not really a workaround - the second-stage compression applied by `pngquant` is part of the file encoding, so the decoded bitmap will always be larger than the size on disk. It's like asking if we can have assembled IKEA furniture and still have it take up only the same space as when it was dissassembled and boxed. What's the end goal you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I'm trying to achieve the following: being able to make a screenshot and then "paste" the compressed version of it somewhere, usually in the browser (twitter, discord, etc). I've tried `SetFileDropList($img)` but even though `GetFileDropList()` says that there's a bitmap in it, it wouldn't let me "paste" the image anywhere, even to Paint